# difference in test statistic and p-value R and Python script

Tags: t-test, p-value

I am trying to compute welch's t-test statistic and p-value manually for educational purpose.

I have written a function for welch's t-test as follows,

```
def welch_t_test(vec_a, vec_b):
    mean_a = vec_a.mean()
    mean_b = vec_b.mean()
    var_a = vec_a.var()
    var_b = vec_b.var()

    T = (mean_a - mean_b)/((var_a-vec_a.size) + (var_b-vec_b.size))
    return T
```

This function returns T-test statistic. To find p-value, I am using `pt` function from `R-3.3.3`.

My example inputs:

```
A = [6,3,0,7,7,0,5,7,7,6]
B = [10,18,14,18,12,13,15,18,16,18]
```

My test statisitc is:

```
Test statistic: -7.065217391304347
```

When I try to compute p-value using `pt` of R like `pt(-7.06521,19)` I get `5.038877e-07` whereas My `R`s defualt `t.test` function result yields test statistic of `-8.1321` and p-value of `1.95e07`. I see the qualitatively both are similar but there exists a quantitative difference. Could someone point out why is that so? And also `df` in R shows some fractional number, in my case `df` of R is `17.987` which I suppose `19` following `n-1` formula for degrees of freedom.

Comment: At first glance--In your first block of code, I think your denominator for the Welch t statistic is incorrect. I will give it a try. It's always a good idea to make sure software is giving answers that agree with known formulas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Welch t statistic:**

Using R as a calculator:

```
A = c(6,3,0,7,7,0,5,7,7,6)
B = c(10,18,14,18,12,13,15,18,16,18)
m = length(A);  n = length(B)
t = ( mean(A) - mean(B) ) / sqrt( var(A)/m + var(B)/n ); t
[1] -8.132062
```

From `t.test` in R, where Welch is the default 2-sample t test.

```
A = c(6,3,0,7,7,0,5,7,7,6)
B = c(10,18,14,18,12,13,15,18,16,18)
t.test(A, B)

        Welch Two Sample t-test

data:  A and B
t = -8.1321, df = 17.987, p-value = 1.95e-07
alternative hypothesis: true difference in means is not equal to 0
95 percent confidence interval:
 -13.086987  -7.713013
sample estimates:
mean of x mean of y 
      4.8      15.2
```

So the two versions agree that $T = -8.1321.$

**Welch degrees of freedom and P-values:**

Traditionally, t distributions had integer degrees of freedom, but the
approximate DF for the Welch t test gives non-integer DF and there is no
problem extending the formula for the density function of t to accommodate
non-integer DF.

The (moderately messy) formula for DF of the Welch test can be found in
many statistics texts and in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Welch%27s_t-test). This formula gives degrees of freedom $\nu$ with
$$ \min(m-1, n-1) \le \nu \le m + n - 2.$$
Roughly speaking $\nu$ is near the upper limit when sample sizes and sample variances are nearly equal.

***Two-sided alternative.*** For the default 2-sided t test, the P-value in R
is obtained using the CDF function `pt`. The result agrees with the rounded
value given in the printout. For closer comparison, the unrounded P-value can be obtained using `$`-notation. (I think the very slight difference is that
R does not print the fractional degrees of freedom to more decimal places.)

```
2 * pt(-8.1321, 17.987)
[1] 1.949439e-07
t.test(A,B)$p.value
[1] 1.949789e-07
```

***Left-sided alternative.*** For a left-sided test, the P-values from `pt` and `t.test` are again in
substantial agreement:

```
pt(-8.1321, 17.987)
[1] 9.747197e-08
t.test(A,B, alt="less")$p.value
[1] 9.748945e-08       # P-value captured from 't.test' procedure

t.test(A,B, alt="less")$parameter
      df 
17.98672  

pt(t.test(A,B, alt="less")$statistic, t.test(A,B, alt="less")$parameter)
           t 
9.748945e-08           # exact agreement with exact DF
```